# Collect the exact time when a specific data has been updated in Firebase via Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, time, firebase-realtime-database

May I ask if there is any implementation to collect the time when the first data is updated. For example, there is a queue function in my app. When an user has taken the queue ticket, Firebase will then be updated.

Therefore, I would like to know the time that the first user in the queue.

Is there any code for this in Android Studio? Many thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure, but have a feeling you're looking for what Firebase calls [server-side timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps). When you write these from an Android app, it passes a "fake" marker value that the Firebase Database server then translates into the actual server-side timestamp.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you! This is what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database does not store metadata (informations like the timestamp) for `CRUD operations` that are performed. Because of that, you need to store this kind of data yourself by creating your own mechanism.

In fact, you need to create a new field for each child you want to trace and change the value of the `timestamp` every time a action is performed. The best practice within a Firebase database is to save your data as a timestamp using: `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

Note, that when you are saving the timestamp, you are saving as a `Map` and when you are retrieving, you are retrieving it as a `long`.

To set the timestamp, I recommend you to use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
rootRef.child("yourNode").updateChildren(map);
```

To get you data back, I recommend you using the following method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Thank you so much! It fits my program! @AlexMamo